# Displaying array results from foorloop - JS

Tags: javascript, laravel

In my controller, when i return `@foreach($cars->drivers as $key=>$value)` i get `4 cars` returned in an array but in my js below, only the last car is displayed. How is this happening in my code below?

PS: Beginner in Javascript & Laravel

**JS**

```
 <script>
 @foreach($cars->drivers as $key=>$value)
  var material = 
  '<div class="input-field col input-g s12">' +
    '<input name="cars_name[]" value="{{$value}}" type="text">' +

   '</div>'
    ;
    @endforeach

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `var material` inside a `foreach` loop. You need to declare it outside of it and than inside of the loop have `material += 'YOUR_CODE'`

It would look something like this:

```
<script>
var material = '';
@foreach{$cars->drivers as $key => $value)
   material += 
     '<div class="input-field col input-g s12">' +
        '<input name="cars_name[]" value="{{$value}}" type="text">' +
     '</div>';
@endforeach
</scrript>
```

Having the material variable inside the foreach loop will only get you the last result because it gets overwritten every them the loop goes trough its elements. This way you are appending the value to an existing variable and will get all the results instead of just the last one

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your variable material inside the foreach loop. So everytime it loops over ,the variable material is declared again with the value from the loop. So the variable is declared with the last assignment in the foreach loop. That's why you are only getting the last item in the list.

You need to declare the variable outside the loop and concat the items in the loop in the variable.

PS: Try to use let and es6 features for better js programming.